# Opencart add reward points to customer's order email

Tags: php, opencart

When a customer places an order I'm trying to add in the rewards points they've earned to their order email.

I know the email for the reward points is sent from
`/admin/model/sale/customer.php` so when I update a customer's reward points manually it mails them with the correct information.

And the email for the order is: `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`

So I just need to get the information the admin file gets and add it into the order.

I've added the appropriate information into the order.tpl and I've added the following into the /model/sale/order.php:

```
$template->data['rewardpoints'] = "";
```

I just now need to put something in place of the quotes and return the reward points the customer has earned.

Ideally how much points the customer earned for this purchase and how much they have in total, but failing that just the points they have in total will suffice.

Anyone any ideas?

Hope that's clear enough.

-James

Comment: What OpenCart version are you using? In 1.5.5.1 in `admin/model/sale/customer.php` there is a method `addReward()` that already sends the mail. So why adding this information to another mail?

Comment: I'm using 1.5.2.1. But I can see the method <pre>addReward()</pre> in that customer file. Quick question, how do I pull in that file so I can use method? Is it just a simple case of of <pre>$this->load->model('sale/customer');</pre> or do I have to add something different as it's in the admin?

Comment: Apologies, can't work out how to format code in the comments.

Comment: You can format comments using `*` and `\`` (backtick for code, asterisk for emphasis or two asterisks for bold text). Yes, it is enough to load the model (if it wasn't yet loaded) by `$this->load->model('sale/customer');` and then you can call the method by `$this->model_sale_customer->addReward($params);` - but I think this method should be called already in some controller when adding reward points to the order.

Comment: That's all quite understandable. But the biggest problem I'm having is it's not adding in the points from THIS order. It only shows me the points the customer has earned prior to this order. The params for `addReward` are `public function addReward($customer_id, $description = '', $points = '', $order_id = 0) {`. The others I can populate, I'm just not sure how to populate the points successfully. In the admin when you add points it obviously takes it from the form. Or am I completely wrong and I can actually use the variable `$params`?

Comment: No, the `$params` I used only to display that the method requires some parameters to be handed over. Of course the `$points` parameter is coming from the form that is responsible for adding the reward points to order. I am starting to getting lost now in this problem - what is the problem exactly? I thought you are in the order details where you can add reward points to it. If You do this then the mail shall be automatically sent to the customer, isn't it?

Comment: Apologies. A customer has placed an order. I'm just trying to add the points earned so far including this order to the order confirmation email. So far I've got the points earned PRIOR to this order showing in the email. (the model is obviously retrieving the customers points first, THEN adding the order into the db, I need it the other way round) As a workaround maybe I can somehow do a mysql statement to get the points earned in this order, and add them to the points earned in previous orders so it will display correctly.

Comment: Finally sorted it. It was a stupid reward points extension that wasn't applying until right at the end of the order.php file, therefore it wasn't taking into account the current transaction. Thanks for everyone's help in working it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to create a simple VQMod, which will add reward points to corresponding controller/model (checkout/order in your case). And only then you can add 'rewardpoints' value to template.

Get reward points for particular order from model:

```
$this->load->model('sale/customer');
$rewardpoints = $this->model->getTotalCustomerRewardsByOrderId($order_id);
```

Assign the value in controller:

```
$template->data['rewardpoints'] = $rewardpoints;
```

Add it to template:

```
echo "You got ".$rewardpoints."points, mon!";
```

Booya!

Comment: The problem with this fix is it shows the points the customer has earned PREVIOUS to this particular transaction. It's not taking into account the points the customer has earned for this transaction. That's ok if I can work out some way of getting the points for the products the customer has bought this transaction, then adding them to their points above.

Comment: Just put these lines BELOW the code, where new reward points assigned.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where you mean. Sorry, I'm not being lazy, just going a bit mad with it all now. I've put the code in the `model/checkout/order.php` just above where it fetches the template

Comment: You definitely doing something wrong then, because reward points for order is added in function addOrder(), which means, when notification email is being prepared, reward is already assigned and MUST be available for parsing.

Comment: I worked it out. It was an extension that was building the `addReward()` at the very end of the document. As soon as I moved that up it was showing the values correctly. Although a quick mention that I couldn't work out how to pull in an admin model into a catalog model, so I redid the specific functions in the order model instead.